# The proper way to handle "Up" Navigation according to guidelines

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, back-stack

I do totally agree with the Navigation below

[image]

Imagine that the Book detail is made in different instances of a BookDetailActivity.

The stack before pressing up in book2 detail is:

- BookDetailActivity (Book 2 - You are here)
- BookDetailActivity (Book 1)
- AllBooksActivity

If I follow the [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) I will use:

```
     Intent parentActivityIntent = new Intent(this, AllBooksActivity.class);
        parentActivityIntent.addFlags(
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(parentActivityIntent);
        finish();
```

But the big problem with this code is that BookDetailActivity (Book 1) is still alive!

Pressing back button after "up" would bring the detail of Book 1.

How can I kill all the `BookDetailActivity` that are between the original `AllBooksActivity` and the activity where I pressed up?

Comment: have you considered using fragments instead of activities ?

Comment: I need a different Activity because I want the animation (if enabled on user device) to create a new "Window" and transitions between whole screens

Comment: as far as i know , you can have transitions between fragments : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int, int, int, int)

Comment: Yes, but not between the whole "window".. And I need to use different Activities, yes.

Comment: ok , added a possible solution .

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand how BookDetailActivity (Book 1) is still alive after you've launched AllBooksActivity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. It should be gone. In fact, when you launch that Intent, all your activities should get finished and a new instance of AllBooksActivity should get created (unless that activity has launchMode="singleTop"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [related guidelines article](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal.html#ancestral-navigation) notes the following:

> Implementation Note: As a best practice, when implementing either Home
>   or Up, make sure to clear the back stack of any descendent screens.
>   For Home, the only remaining screen on the back stack should be the
>   home screen. For Up navigation, the current screen should be removed
>   from the back stack, unless Back navigates across screen hierarchies.
>   You can use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   intent flags together to achieve this.

Since you're doing that, BookDetailActivity1 should be closed by [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP). The only way if it could be alive and shown on pressing Back is if it would have been started before AllBooksActivity.

As for not needing [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) (suggested by *android developer*'s answer):

> When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity
>   you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started;
>   instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the
>   screen with the state it was last in.

...so if your activity exists, it will not start a new task.

Comment: As far as the new task flag goes, your comment may be true but why add the flag in the first place? It doesn't seem like a new task to me.

Comment: It might not be needed in all cases. But if users can launch BookDetailsActivity from outside the app (from a notification, by scanning a code etc.), it makes sense. See the last example (Navigating between apps to support sharing) in this article: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 1):

ok , there are multiple ways to do such a thing. here's one of them:

however , i would suggest that instead of opening the first activity as if it's a new one , simply finish the current one and the one before it .

in order to do it , call each new activity with startActivityForResult , and set the result for each of the activities to some value that says you wish to return to the first activity .

you can even set the value to be the class canonical name , and make a base activity that will handle all of those requests automatically so that you won't need to handle it .

in any case , i think you made a mistake by using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK since it creates a new task , so the previous one still exists . try to read the available intents flags for more information:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Sounds like deverloper blog is not accurate: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: well if google was more opened in their posts , i could have commented there that they have a mistake :) . i'm sure this is not the only mistake .

Comment: anyway , you can check the samples of both google and actionBarSherlock and see how it should work.